# をきっかけに vs をいいことに

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances

I read this sample sentence [here](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%82%92%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%81%AB-o-kikkake-ni/):

> 留学をきっかけに、自分の国についていろいろ考えるようになった。
>
> Studying abroad was **a good opportunity** for me to think about my
>   own country.

This reminded me of this [grammar point](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%82%92%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB-o-ii-koto-ni/): をいいことに

So, what is the difference between the two? Are they interchangeable in this context? Which one feels more natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry in advance for my unnatural English. If you don't understand what I'm saying, feel free to point out my mistakes.

To answer your question, をいいことに takes on a nuance of criticism. For example, quoting from [this site](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%82%92%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB-o-ii-koto-ni/),

> 先生がいないのをいいことに学校をサボった。
>
> I took advantage of the teacher’s absence and skipped school.

In this sentence, the writer of this sentence criticizes the one who skipped school. In short, the writer is criticizing himself jokingly.

So, in "留学をきっかけに、自分の国についていろいろ考えるようになった。", をいいことに is NOT suitable. In general, をきっかけに and をいいことに are not interchangeable.

Comment: From the same source: ドアが開いているのをいいことに、三階に抜け出した = "I took advantage of the open door ...". I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "critical wording". It seemed to make sense in the example in your answer, but I'm struggling to understand it with this sentence.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you don't understand. In the sentence you quoted, the writer criticizes who "escaped toward the third floor". I don't know why the writer criticizes it, but it seems that escaping is considered to be a bad thing in this context.

Or, is "critical wording" confusing? [rebuuilt](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/29327/rebuuilt) kindly suggested editing my answer, and をいいことに is now explained as "takes on a nuance of criticism". Dose it answer your question?

Comment: Maybe in ドアが開いているのをいいことに、三階に抜け出した, the doer of the action was supposed to be locked up in that room--maybe because he was a kid grounded by his parents, or a patient who just recovered from COVID-19 and was told not to leave to avoid possible spread of disease.